# Put HTML in javascript using Ruby

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sinatra, haml

**Note:** This is a very strange and unique use case so I apologise in advance if it seems a bit ass-backwards.

I have a haml file `content.haml` and a coffeescript file `main.coffee`.
I wish to somehow get the html resulting from rendering content.haml into a variable in the coffeescript/resulting javascript.

The end result should be a javascript file rendered to the browser.

let's say they look like this:

```
# content.haml
.container
  .some_content
    blah blah blah
```

-

```
# main.coffee
html_content = ???
do_something_with_html_content(html_content)
```

I know, this sounds ridiculous, 'use templates', 'fetch the HTML via ajax' etc. In this instance however, it's not possible, everything needs to be served via one JS file and I cannot fetch other resources from the server. Weird, I know.

Short of manually reconstructing the haml in the coffeescript file by joining an array of strings like this:

```
html_content = [
  '<div class"container">',
    '<div class"some_content">',
      'blah blah blah',
    '</div>',
  '</div>',
]
```

I'm not sure the best way of doing this.

Another way I though of was to put something like this in the coffee file:

```
html_content = '###CONTENT###'
```

Then render the haml to html in ruby, render the coffeescript to js and then replace `###CONTENT###` with the rendered html before serving to the client. However the html is a multi-line string so it completely destroys the javascript.

I'm convinced there must be some other nice way of rendering the haml into html in a variable such that it forms valid javascript, but my brain has gone blank.

Comment: Can you put your coffeescript code inside HAML or it has to stay seperate in a different file?

Comment: It doesn't matter so long as the result is a JS file rendered to the client. I hadn't thought of it the other way around but I'm not sure how that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this in one of your views:

```
:javascript
   html_content = <%= escape_javascript(render partial: "content")%>
   ## your own logic follows here....
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use a [custom html `data` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) and then fetch the content of it in js?

```
<div data-mycontent="YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE"></div>
```

And then in coffee, use the `dataset` attribute / data via jquery, if it is available.

If you set a var via writing the file directly it will render your `js` file uncacheable, among other drawbacks.

Comment: The HTML/haml won't change so the resulting JS file can be cached (manually). Also, I don't have access to the page's HTML, just the JS (like I said - weird use case..) so unfortunately I can't use HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the sprockets gem, like Rails does. You just need to rename your CoffeeScript file to `main.coffee.erb` and use it as you would e.g. a haml template. Pass in your rendered html with an instance variable:

```
html_content = '<%= @html_content %>'
```

**Edit**: Added missing quotes.

Comment: My issue with this is that @html_content could contain a large multi-line html string which wouldn't be javascript-safe. Is there any easy way to avoid this?

Comment: I added the missing single quotes to the example. You can escape all single quotes from the HTML: `@html_content.gsub!("'", "\'")` This way multiple lines of HTML won't be a problem. If the html you pass in is user-generated, you might want to extend the match pattern to deal with already escaped quotes as well.

Comment: That fixes single quote, but not newlines, I guess I could just gsub everything but it doesn't feel very comprehensive...

Comment: Newlines in strings should be no problem, are they? If so, just escape them as well or remove them.